# .reduce() is changing all my variables when im not changing them

Tags: vue.js

i'm using VueTables-2 and im trying to change the information shown in real time when changing the value of a select.
Im just using .reduce() to "group" the articles and add up the commission property of them, but every time i change from the default view 'articles' to 'articles-grouped' and again to 'articles', it keeps the value shown before ( for example, we have 3 article codes, which 2 of them are the same, so when i group them, the final elements are 2 because the ones that where the same article code summed up, so when i change to individual article codes view, it shows the commission from the grouped article, not the starter one).

Here's the code:

```
Vue.use(Vuetable); //--uso vuetable-2

new Vue({
    el: '#commissions-table',
    components: {
        'vuetable-pagination': Vuetable.VuetablePagination
    },
    data: {
        agent_code: AGENT_CODE,
        search: '',
        type: 'articles',
        tab: 'articles',
        isloading: 1,
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'article_code',
                title: 'Article Code',
                sortField: 'article_code'
            },
            {
                name: 'quantity',
                sortField: 'quantity',
                callback: 'print_quantity'
            },
            {
                name: 'commission',
                title: 'Commission',
                sortField: 'commission',
                callback: 'print_price'
            },
            {
                name: 'invoice_date',
                title: 'Invoice date',
                sortField: 'invoice_date',
                callback: 'print_invoice_date'
            },
            '__slot:actions'
        ],
        perPage: 25,
        main_data: [],
        vuetable_data: [],
        css: {
            table: {
                tableClass: 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered',
                loadingClass: 'loading',
                ascendingIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
                descendingIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
                handleIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger',
            },
            pagination: {
                infoClass: 'pull-left',
                wrapperClass: 'vuetable-pagination pull-right',
                activeClass: 'btn-primary',
                disabledClass: 'disabled',
                pageClass: 'btn btn-border',
                linkClass: 'btn btn-border',
                icons: {
                    first: '',
                    prev: '',
                    next: '',
                    last: '',
                },
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        /*httpOptions(){
          return {headers: {'Authorization': "my-token"}} //table props -> :http-options="httpOptions"
        },*/
    },
    template: `
    <div id="table-wrapper" class="ui container">
    <button @click="tab = 'articles';type = 'articles'">Articles</button>
    <button @click="tab = 'invoices';type = 'invoices'">Invoices</button>

    <input v-model="search">
    
    <select v-if="tab=='articles'" v-model="type" @change="type_change(type)">
        <option selected="selected" value="articles">Individual articles</option>
        <option value="articles_grouped">Grouped articles</option>
    </select>
    <select v-else-if="tab=='invoices'" v-model="type">
        <option selected="selected" value="invoices">Individual invoices</option>
        <option value="invoices-by-clients">Invoices grouped by clients</option>
    </select>

    <vuetable ref="vuetable"
        :data = "vuetable_data"
        :api-mode="false"
        :fields="fields"
        :xcss="css.table"
        :data-manager="dataManager"
        pagination-path="pagination"
        @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
        @vuetable:loading="onLoading"        
        @vuetable:loaded="onLoaded"
        @vuetable-pagination:change-page="onChangePage"
    >
     <template slot="actions" scope="props">
       <div class="table-button-container">
           <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" @click="editRow(props.rowData)">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="deleteRow(props.rowData)">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       </div>
       </template>
     </vuetable>
     <vuetable-pagination ref="pagination"
       :css="css.pagination"
       @vuetable-pagination:change-page="onChangePage"
     ></vuetable-pagination>
     <loadingfullpage :isloading="isloading" />
   </div>`
    ,
    watch: {

        // type(newVal, oldVal) {
        //     console.log(newVal);
        //     console.log(this.main_data);
        //     switch (newVal) {
        //         case 'articles':
        //             this.vuetable_data = this.main_data; break;
        //         case 'articles_grouped': 
        //         var tmp_data = this.main_data;
        //         this.vuetable_data = tmp_data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        //             var item = acc.find(aaa => aaa.article_code === curr.article_code);

        //             if (item) {
        //                 item.commission = (Number(item.commission) + Number(curr.commission)).toFixed(2);
        //             } else {
        //               acc.push(curr);
        //             }

        //             return acc;
        //           }, []);
        //             ; break;
        //         case 'invoices': ; break;
        //         case 'invoices_by_clients': ; break;
        //         default: ; break;
        //     }
        //     console.log(this.main_data);
        // },
        search(newVal, oldVal) {
            var tmp_array = [];
            const normalize = str => _.toLower(_.deburr(str))

            const includesValue = (val, obj) => {
                const search = normalize(val)
                return _.some(obj, v => normalize(v).includes(search))
            }
            const search = newVal.toLowerCase();
            _.forEach(this.main_data, function (data) {
                if (includesValue(search, data)) {
                    tmp_array.push(data);
                }
            });
            this.vuetable_data = tmp_array;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        type_change(newVal) {
            console.log(newVal, 'TYPE CHANGE');
            console.log(this.main_data);
            switch (newVal) {
                case 'articles':
                    this.vuetable_data = this.main_data; break;
                case 'articles_grouped':
                    const tmp_data = this.main_data;
                    this.vuetable_data = tmp_data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                        var item = acc.find(aaa => aaa.article_code === curr.article_code);

                        if (item) {
                            item.commission = (Number(item.commission) + Number(curr.commission)).toFixed(2);
                        } else {
                            acc.push(curr);
                        }

                        return acc;
                    }, []);
                    ; break;
                case 'invoices': ; break;
                case 'invoices_by_clients': ; break;
                default: ; break;
            }
            console.log(this.main_data);
        },
        toggle_loading() {

            if (this.isloading)
                this.isloading = 0;
            else
                this.isloading = 1;

        },
        onPaginationData(paginationData) {
            this.$refs.pagination.setPaginationData(paginationData);
        },
        onChangePage(page) {
            this.$refs.vuetable.changePage(page);
        },
        dataManager(sortOrder, pagination) {
            if (this.vuetable_data.length < 1) return;

            let local = this.vuetable_data;

            // sortOrder can be empty, so we have to check for that as well
            if (sortOrder.length > 0) {
                console.log("orderBy:", sortOrder[0].sortField, sortOrder[0].direction);
                local = _.orderBy(
                    local,
                    sortOrder[0].sortField,
                    sortOrder[0].direction
                );
            }

            pagination = this.$refs.vuetable.makePagination(
                local.length,
                this.perPage
            );
            console.log('pagination:', pagination)
            let from = pagination.from - 1;
            let to = from + this.perPage;

            return {
                pagination: pagination,
                data: _.slice(local, from, to)
            };
        },
        onActionClicked(action, data) {
            console.log("slot actions: on-click", data.name);
        },

        editRow(rowData) {
            alert("You clicked edit on" + JSON.stringify(rowData));
        },
        deleteRow(rowData) {
            alert("You clicked delete on" + JSON.stringify(rowData))
        },
        onLoading() {
            console.log('loading... show your spinner here')
        },
        onLoaded() {
            console.log('loaded! .. hide your spinner here')
        },
        print_invoice_date(date) {
            return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        },
        print_quantity(qty) {
            return qty + ' pcs';
        },
        print_price(price) {
            return price + ' €';
        }
    },
    mounted() {

        var url2call = WEBROOT + 'commissions/get_info.json';
        _this = this;
        axios.post(url2call, { agent_code: this.agent_code }).then(
            function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res.data.status) {
                    _this.vuetable_data = res.data.data;
                    _this.main_data = res.data.data;

                }
                else
                    alert(res.data.message);
                _this.toggle_loading();

            },
            function (err) {
                _this.toggle_loading();
                alert(`Ajax error: ${err.statusText} (${err.status})`)
            });
    }
})
```

Comment: It's hard to follow the example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Most times the described problem means that an object is mutated and reused. Here, `item.commission =`. If you don't want to change a variable, don't change it.

Comment: i want to change it, but only in the array im calling first.. not all of them

Comment: Then don't change an existing object, copy it.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I mean that you need to make a copy of `item` and not mutate original `item`. Otherwise the object and its changes will be shared between arrays.

Comment: Im doing it xD main_data is never edited, only vuetable

Comment: Again, you mutate `item` object. If it's the same in both places (I cannot confirm because the code is too bulky to read), it will appear modified in both places. Objects are used by reference in JS. If you're unaware of this, I'd suggest to study this topic first. In order to NOT mutate `item`, you need to NOT do `item.commission =`. Instead, make a copy of `item` with modified data.

Comment: No, item object is inside reduce, it doesnt mutate, it's a object that only exist in the .reduce() function

Comment: I'm quite sure it's not. The problem that you describe suggests that you misunderstood how it works.  `item` is the same object in `main_data` and `vuetable_data`. If you change it in one array, it's changed in another, these are the fundamentals of JS Try to make a copy instead. I can't help here in another way. Consider reasking the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The example should really be *minimal* and *complete* in order for other users to be able to understand what happens in your code without spending much time digging into it.

Comment: just look at the code, i've saved the main info in another variable, and then i used a .reduce() in that variable, how is it posible that main_data was edited, if i saved it before in another variable

Comment: You miss the basics of JS here. Objects are used by by reference in JS. This means that both arrays contain pointers to the same data in memory. What you do here is basically `let o = { b: 1 }; let a1 = [o]; let a2 = [o]`. They are different arrays that contain the same object. And you can be sure that `a1[0] === a2[0]`. They refer to the same object, literally. There's only 1 object here, unless you explicitly did a copy of it. If you do `a1[0].b = 2`, this means that `a1[0].b === 2` and `a2[0].b === 2`.

Comment: omg, i got it now, thank you so much